# Change color of matching parentheses in Teradata Studio Express

Tags: sql, windows, teradata

Is there any way to change the color of matching parentheses SQL Editor query window. I checked in the options for text editor but I cant find it anywhere.

I'm using Teradata Studio Express version:17.00.12.00.202012260107. On Windows 10 1909.

Comment: No. You can toggle auto-completion of parentheses, but not parens matching colors. For what it's worth, since I see you have three questions open here, you may want to check out DBeaver. It's not made specifically for Teradata, but it's extremely configurable.

Comment: And how to toggle it?